# jQuery - Making my own slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm still learning jQuery, and I know that what I'm asking is probably quite redundant as there are hundreds of sliders out there already that will be much better than the final outcome of mine.

However, I'm trying to learn by doing and I set myself the task of making a slider, so any help you can give me would be great!

**Here's what I have so far:** http://jsfiddle.net/eLgBG/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.thumb').click(function(event){
        var idAttr = $(this).attr('rel');


        $('.thumb').removeClass('active');  
        $(this).addClass('active');


        $('.banner').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
        $('.banner-' + idAttr).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);


        if($('.thumb').hasClass('active')){
            return false;
        }


    })
});
```

**The main things I'd like to achieve:**

- When you click a thumbnail to go back to a previous slide, the slider goes backwards instead of forwards.
- The Second Slide doesn't come in straight away, for some reason it shows white first?  The rest don't do this though which is weird
- When you click a tab that is already active, I don't want it to do anything.
  I've tried to fix this one but I can't get it to work

  ```
      if($('.thumb').hasClass('active')){
          return false;
      }
  ```

Any help would be great, thank you!! :)

Comment: Just a recommendation for the future. Use softer colours in your demo. Really can't stand to look at it because the harsh colours hurt my eyes.

Comment: Commonly called a "carousel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix your 1st and 3rd bullet:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9tJc/1/

Basically, the trick is to store the current slide:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var currentRel = -1;

        $('.thumb').click(function(event){
            var idAttr = $(this).attr('rel');

            $('.thumb').removeClass('active');  
            $(this).addClass('active');

            if(parseInt(idAttr)>currentRel) {
                $('.banner').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
                $('.banner-' + idAttr).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
            }
            else if(parseInt(idAttr)<currentRel) {
                $('.banner').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
                $('.banner-' + idAttr).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
            }

            currentRel = parseInt(idAttr);

        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  It took me a minute to understand what you did but I get it!  If you don't mind me asking, how did this stop the active tab from still sliding?

Comment: Because the ( currentRel == parseInt(idAttr) ) takes no action :)

Comment: Thanks for that :)  While the first tab is still active on load, it will still scroll on the first click even though that's what's already shown.  Do you know any way of preventing that?  Thanks :)

Comment: Yes; just change "var currentRel = -1;"   for   "var currentRel = 1;"